# 3 phase 208v leg balance and observed KVA

Tags: current, ups, power-factor-correction, balanced

I have a cluster computer system in a small server room, fed by an 80 kva capable double conversion (480v 3-phase in, 208v single phase out) UPS.  This UPS has an LCD display showing voltage, leg amperage for A-B, B-C, C-A, and total kva.

The computer system has 8 total L6-30 power cables going to some 20+ available wall receptacles.  Upon initial operation we observed on the ups display a somewhat imbalanced current draw across the ABC legs (something like 17, 19, 24 amps I am ball parking from memory it wasn't a huge imbalance).  After identifying all the wall receptacles as to what AB BC CA legs they go to we moved one L6 power cable to a different wall receptacle and that balanced out the current draw.  But even with the *imbalance*, we saw a constant draw such as ~12 kva at idle, and ~22 kva under hpl cpu stress; both observations were a constant value plus or minus 1 kva.

Fast forward to now we added some additional equipment and are renovating I powered the computer system on knowing the L6 power cables are not going to the correct receptacles to achieve a balanced leg current draw.  According to the UPS display any leg imbalance right now is no worse than previously, but with the computer system just on at idle the UPS display goes from 17.0 kva to 20.5 kva and back consistently.  I have no reason to suspect a problem with the UPS system displaying improperly, however I have never seen this display behavior before.

While the display probably updates no quicker than 1 second intervals this constant back and forth between 17 kva and 20 kva (plus or minus 1 kva) is about 15% is it not?  Is this indicative of some kind of problem and could anyone tell me in electrical engineering terms if this is the result of an imbalanced draw across the UPS legs and if so the how's and why's and terminology surrounding it?  And what tools would best further diagnose this odd behavior?  The computer equipment is brand new and I did not see this UPS display behavior when the computer was initially installed, powered up, and bench marked.  I also assume that the power factor is greater than 0.9 given the only type of equipment being powered is network switches and server power supplies.

Comment: Search subharmonics or subharmonic instability.

Comment: Is there any evidence of unusual battery charge activity? The battery side has aged too, and may have been disturbed by the changes.

Comment: First try to find the power factor of the installation. Remember that modern computers convert ac into dc before further processing. From there you could work forwards